How can I execute strings as robot framework code (Robot version 3.1.1)?
I'm using robot version 3.1.1 for test automation.
I have a JSON file that stores robot login commands based on the host name.
{
   "host1" : ["Open Connection  host1", "Login  host1", ....]
}

I'm able to parse the JSON file, but how can I execute the strings as robot code?
This is what I tried:
 ${source_data} =  OperatingSystem.Get File  ${CURDIR}/auth.json
 ${data} =  Evaluate  json.loads($source_data)  json

 : FOR ${command}  IN  @{data["host1"]}
     \  Evaluate  robot.run(${command})

I end up getting an error like this:
Evaluating expression 'robot.run(Open Connection  host1)' failed: SytntaxError: invalid syntax(, line 1)

Issue comes from the fact that you your arguments are part of the keyword name.. You should split the ${command}, first in to 2 parts at first case where there's more spaces than one.. Then the last element should be split into as many elements as it has.

Also, there's "Run Keyword" keyword that you can use instead of  Evaluate   robot.run()
